# Is there a way to find all jobs on Jenkins that affect a table?

Tags: jenkins

I would like to find all jobs on Jenkins that affect a table. For example, let's say I have 3 jobs:

project name: build-subscriptions-table
build: `CREATE TABLE public.subscriptions AS...`

project name: refresh-subscriptions-table
build: `UPDATE TABLE public.subscriptions SET...`

project name: update-user-sources 
build: `UPDATE TABLE public.subscriptions SET...`

So if I'm interested in all jobs that affect the `public.subscriptions` table, I would like to return all of the above jobs. Is there a search function that does this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the server you can recursively grep/search the `JENKINS_HOME/jobs` directory for files containing the string

```
TABLE public.subscriptions
```